# A table loaded with a database in the datagridview does not display the first line

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview, datatable

I load a table with a database in a DataGridView in this way. I have a datagridview displayed in all lines except the first. What is the problem?

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows == false)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.Visible = true;
                    DataTable dt = null;
                    dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(reader);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                    if (reader.IsClosed == true)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you reading a CSV file?  The first row will become the columns names and not be put into the 1st row.

Comment: Does the first line of the csv contain the column names? Do you see these names in the column headers of the DataGridView?

Comment: No, I read the SQL Server DB. Yes, I can see the headlines in a datagridview, well and without them there is no first line.

Comment: [Screenshot DB and Datagridview](http://www.picshare.ru/uploads/170217/Cnfs5tp55i.png)
PS: Sorry for that there is not in English.

Answer (score 0):

Used following codesnippet and it worked flawless on my end

```
    private void Request(string request) {

    var dt = new DataTable();

    try {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(request, connectionString);
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read()) {
            dt.Load(reader);
            if (reader.IsClosed) break;
        }
        reader.Close();
    } catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

try that, and if that wont work check your request String

Comment: be a bit more accurate what did not work well? I tested this with a 5.000 rows and 20 colums database without any issue

Comment: I realized what the problem is, I do not have the desired DataTable in line, although it is in the database. I checked in this way:
`for (int curRow = 0; curRow <dt.Rows.Count; curRow ++)
    for (int curCol = 0; curCol <dt.Columns.Count; curCol ++)
                                  Console.WriteLine (dt.Rows [curRow] [curCol] .ToString () + "\ t");`

Comment: But SqlDataReader Reader also checked here in this code and there it is necessary first line is:
 `private void ReadSingleRow (IDataRecord record)
         {
             string dat = null;

             for (int i = 0; i <record.FieldCount; i ++)
             {
                 dat + = record [i] + ",";
             }

             Console.WriteLine (dat);
         }`

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working. It was necessary to remove the cycle `reader.Read()`. Thanks for the help!

```
private void Request(string request)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(request, connectionString);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows == false)
                {
                     dataGridView1.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.Visible = true;
                    var dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(reader);

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString(), e.Source.ToString());
            }
        }
```